# Ruby on rails - how to convert array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
(byebug) content_item.parent_id
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `parent_id' for [#<ContentItemRelationship id: "6186d48b-cdc3-4c83-bea1-3db01d614db8", parent_id: "ac123044-730c-42b8-a220-0b38d6ebe20c", content_item_id: "e0734b6d-76e4-4acf-858f-3c91782f2975", order: nil, created_at: "2022-09-19 13:03:50.430928000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-09-19 13:03:50.430928000 +0000">]:Array
```

why this error is coming please help me. data bellow :

object `content_item` contain  -

```
[#<ContentItemRelationship id: "6186d48b-cdc3-4c83-bea1-3db01d614db8", parent_id: "ac123044-730c-42b8-a220-0b38d6ebe20c", content_item_id: "e0734b6d-76e4-4acf-858f-3c91782f2975", order: nil, created_at: "2022-09-19 13:03:50.430928000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-09-19 13:03:50.430928000 +0000">]
```

Comment: `content_item.first.parent_id`

Comment: `content_item` is actually an array, hence the enclosing `[...]`. Where does `content_item` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @mechnicov highlighted, here content_item is an array that's when you're getting an error for `content_item.parent_id`. You need to get the value inside that array using either `content_item.first.parent_id` or `content_item.last.parent_id`. This way you'd be able to get parent_id for the content item.